# Can you recommend a book with techniques for solving hard algebra/arithmetic problems?

Tags: arithmetic, book-recommendation

I'm a university student who never really studied maths in high school (I did the basic courses, but because I'm dyslexic I was to embarrassed to try the harder courses) now I'm getting back into it, and, while I'm perfectly fine with understanding the advanced concepts and grasping the theoretical side of things, I have a lot of trouble with the arithmetic in the harder questions. A lot of this is due to my not really knowing a lot of the techniques used in manipulating terms in complex fractions and just generally not having a good set of problem solving tools to fall back on.

Can you recommend any books that deal with arithmetic techniques for more advanced problems?

just to give you an idea, here are some examples of question formats that I would like to practice:

**number 1**
$$
\frac{x^{2}}{y}+\frac{y^{2}}{x}
$$

where $x = 2 + \sqrt{3}$ and $y = 2 - \sqrt{3}$

**Number 2**

factorise $54x^3 + 16$

**number 3**

given that $$a^{2}+b^{2} = 7ab$$

express $$\left(\frac{a+b}{3}\right)^{2}$$

in terms of a and b. Hence show that $$\log\left (\frac{a+b}{3}\right )=\frac{1}{2}\left(\log a+\log b \right)$$

if would be especially great if it had lots of practice questions.

Thanks.

Comment: Some people here will give you answers better than any book (for the symbolic price of one up-vote and one click on the V next to the answer). Some will give you not-so-good answers as well, but crowed-wisdom will allow you to easily differentiate them from the good ones.

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment, Though to be honest I'm not looking for answers so much as practice questions.

Comment: It's not so much "techniques" as it is practice. Also, keep an eye out for hard algebra or arithmetical problems on this site (some of which will be in the guise of "how do you prove this well known formula" type questions). Read the answers and try to digest how they work and file the ideas away for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the text *Algebra* by I. M. Gelfand and A. Shen.  It was one of a series of texts written for bright high school students in the Soviet Union who wished to supplement the high school curriculum through correspondence courses with professors at the University of Moscow.  Working through this clearly written text will enhance your understanding of algebra and develop your problem-solving skills. The text is available in English translation.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at 'How to solve it - George Polya'. It's more general but quite helpful.